# What's the purpose of admin canonical tag?

Tags: wp-admin, rel-canonical

I have searched through Google and [WordPress developer resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=wp-admin-canonical), but nothing came up.

I understand the purpose of `rel="canonical"` tag in a website's frontend (it's part of the website SEO), but I fail to understand its purpose in WordPress Admin area (backend).

Example in a local WordPress installation:

```
<link id="wp-admin-canonical" rel="canonical" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/plugins.php" />
```

What is their purpose in WordPress Admin area?

Comment: "admin" pages are also part of the website

Comment: In frontend, it's part of the website SEO. In backend, you don't need SEO.

Comment: there is no such thing as "frontend". The distinction between "frontend" and "backend" is just a mental one, but has nothing to do with code or standards

Comment: ... so the answer is (probably) that it is part of the standard, it should be always done unless you have a good reason not to, and at least right now you didn't supply a reason to not do it. Just because you do not see a usage do not mean someone else will not see one.

Comment: That's exactly why I asked the question, to find out it's purpose. Read again my question!

Comment: last time, there should never be a reason to follow the rule of thumb. Reasons should be only to avoid it

Comment: @Fayaz please stop editing my question again

Comment: @BinarWeb it's OK in WPSE if someone edits your question to include more relevant information. In fact, someone may edit my answer if s/he thinks editing would make it better. That's how the community works. However, if you think my edit diverted your question from your original intent, I apologize. In that case, you can always revert it back to the original. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### What is frontend & what is backend in WordPress?

The PHP CODE, SQL Queries etc. that are executed on your server is the **backend** & any HTML/CSS/JavaScript CODE that comes to the browser as a result, is the **frontend**.

So even though, some parts of your site's **"frontend"** may be restricted by a password protected barrier, it's still considered as frontend. It's more accurate if you call it **WordPress Admin Panel**, instead of calling it the backend.

### Why would WordPress Admin Panel pages need `rel="canonical"`?

Unless for a **very very rare** use case where you may make the admin pages public, there can be no SEO benefits from it. However, `rel="canonical"` can still be used (even for the admin panel pages): **As part of the standard practice**.

For a web page, `rel="canonical"` means:

> The web page URL that is recognized as the go to URL for a collection of different pages having very similar or the same content.

Since this is the standard practice, even if you don't get any SEO benefit from it, it's still the right thing to do.

### Where does it come from:

WordPress added `wp_admin_canonical_url()` function in WordPress 4.2. `rel="canonical"` part was there from the beginning & WordPress developers found no reason to remove it since then.

The original change came from the support ticket titled: [Remove message parameters from admin URl's in the browser address bar](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23367). And if you go through the discussion, you'll see that the `rel=canonical` part was added as part of standard practice, **nothing more**.

Check the [comment](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23367#comment:25) from the original developer:

> 3. `rel=canonical` is a standard practice, and I think this is a good use of it.

### Why WordPress needs the `<link id="wp-admin-canonical" />` tag?

As evident from the above discussion, `rel=canonical` part of the `<link>` tag is only there for standard practice, however, the `<link>` tag:

```
<link id="wp-admin-canonical" rel="canonical" href="__URL__" />
```

itself is functional. It was added to keep the URL & browser history clean from **single-use query variable names**.

For example, if you activate a Plugin, at the top of your admin panel, it gives you a message like:

> Plugin activated.

After that, say you close the browser & open it back again later (or simply refresh the page). At that point, prior to WordPress 4.2 (if the browser is set to open the last opened tab), the page would still say:

> Plugin activated

even though nothing really happened this time. Same applies when you use browser back button (because the message is shown in response to the single-use URL parameters from browser history as well).

This happens because WordPress redirects you to a URL like:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php?activate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s=
```

after you activate a plugin. Notice the `activate=true` query string in the URL. This has no purpose other than showing you that "**Plugin activated**" message. So it has no use in the URL or browser history after the "**Plugin activated**" message is delivered to you.

That's why, in WordPress 4.2 [`wp_admin_canonical_url()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.7/src/wp-admin/includes/misc.php#L1076) function was introduced, where `<link id="wp-admin-canonical" />` tag keeps the reference to the canonical version of the URL without the **single-use query variable** part & then the JavaScript CODE from the function replaces it from the browser's history entry.

As of writing this, there are 23 such **single-use query variables** that can be removed from the canonical URL from [`wp_removable_query_args()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.7/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L857) function:

```
'activate', 'activated', 'approved', 'deactivate', 'deleted',
'disabled', 'enabled', 'error', 'hotkeys_highlight_first', 
'hotkeys_highlight_last', 'locked', 'message', 'same', 'saved',
'settings-updated', 'skipped', 'spammed', 'trashed', 'unspammed', 
'untrashed', 'update', 'updated', 'wp-post-new-reload'
```

However, it can be extended from Plugins or Themes using the `removable_query_args` filter hook.

Comment: LOL, so I am actually to be blamed in this. Probably didn't follow the ticket at the time they decided to add rel canonical though.

Comment: Well the ticket was closed 2 years after you opened it. So I don't blame you for not following the discussion ;)

Answer (score 4):

Wordpress use this in the admin to remove some query args from the url.

Its generated by the function [`wp_admin_canonical_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_admin_canonical_url/)

```
function wp_admin_canonical_url() {
    $removable_query_args = wp_removable_query_args();

    if ( empty( $removable_query_args ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Ensure we're using an absolute URL.
    $current_url  = set_url_scheme( 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
    $filtered_url = remove_query_arg( $removable_query_args, $current_url );
    ?>
    <link id="wp-admin-canonical" rel="canonical" href="<?php echo esc_url( $filtered_url ); ?>" />
    <script>
        if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
            window.history.replaceState( null, null, document.getElementById( 'wp-admin-canonical' ).href + window.location.hash );
        }
    </script>
<?php
}
```

The [`wp_removable_query_args()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_removable_query_args/) return an array with the query args that we want to remove the default ones for example.

```
$removable_query_args = array(
    'activate',
    'activated',
    'approved',
    'deactivate',
    'deleted',
    'disabled',
    'enabled',
    'error',
    'hotkeys_highlight_first',
    'hotkeys_highlight_last',
    'locked',
    'message',
    'same',
    'saved',
    'settings-updated',
    'skipped',
    'spammed',
    'trashed',
    'unspammed',
    'untrashed',
    'update',
    'updated',
    'wp-post-new-reload',
);
```

So now for example if we edit some post the url is `http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=32&action=edit`

When we save the post we change the url to `/wp-admin/post.php?post=32&action=edit&message=1` but with JS we change the url that stored in our browser history with `window.history.replaceState` and remove the `message` query arg.

And then if we change the url and click back we will back to our stored url instead of the url with the `message`.

And we won't see the message: **Post updated. View post** again.

It can be tested with creating new post you can see the message and then go to homepage and click back. and see that you won't see the message because our browser history url changed to be without the message query arg.

**So why use the `rel="canonical"`?**

From what I see wordpress core doesn't have a real purpose except **semantics** to use this tag. This tag are meant to tell us that the some url is duplicate to other url.

But as other crawlers used this tag as an option to check for duplications we can build our own crawler to our admin area for some purpose and we can use this tag.

Comment: Down voted because: even though your answer is very good for: "what is the purpose of `wp_admin_canonical_url()` function?"; it doesn't say anything **at all** about the OP's question: "Why `rel="canonical"` is used there?". For example: I can do all that without placing `rel="canonical"` in this link: `<link id="wp-admin-canonical" href="__Admin_URL__" />`.

Comment: @Scott I've edited my answer. why use `rel="canonical"` too.

Comment: OK, I've removed the down vote, as it now touches the original question. However, I still think **your answer includes a lot of unnecessary details that the OP didn't ask**. As I said, this would've been a good answer only if the question was something like: "what is the purpose of `wp_admin_canonical_url()` function?". Clearly this is not that question :)

Comment: @Scott In this case I think its important to understand what wordpress doing with tag and not only why use this tag. Because without it its like asking why use `section` over `div`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no valid reason to have one in the backend (aka admin). The only one is that the function `rel_canonical` in `wp-includes/link-template.php` added from the action in `default-filters.php` file is always activated - regardless if it is front or backend.

And as the behaviour does not seem to be a problem to the community, it is left unchanged : the developer working on Wordpress would spend their time better improving something important than something that wouldn't add any value to Wordpress.